# electrolyte dependency injection from unittest using mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

In electrolyte.js we generally create a module: emodule.js (example)

```
exports=module.exports=function(module1,module2,module3){



};


exports["@singleton"]=true;
exports["@require"] = ["module1","module2","module3"]
```

Now if we want to actually mock module2 in mocha test how should we invoke the emodule.js such that all calls to module2 will be redirected to the mock ? thanks for any pointer...

Answer (score 2):

Have you see other dependency injection container systems like bottlejs (https://github.com/young-steveo/bottlejs) or SimpleDiJs (https://github.com/avighier/simple-dijs) ?